# How do i remove the spaces between RecycleView items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, space

i have a recycle view of texts but cannot get rid of the spaces between them. I tried zeroing the padding but nothing. This is the recycler xml:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Its child of a Constraint Layout

This is the xml of the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itLkq.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the whole code of your child item layout and it'll be nice if you can show the screenshot

Comment: Code & screenshot added. You can see the two texts in the list, in the center of the screen and their distance

Comment: In your list item xml, you should set the ConstraintLayout layout_height to be "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent".

Comment: That was it, thank you all!

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser I see that a similar answer was already accepted, so no need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of `ConstraintLayout` in XML to `wrap_content`

Change height from

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

to

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

make `matchparent` in constraint layout to wrap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```